# real name of Iterate-Erase Idiom

Tags: c++, idioms

When you want to iterate over a container, perform some action, and erase
some of it based on some criteria, in one pass, what you do is:

```
auto iter = container.begin()
while( iter != container.end() )
{
    SomeAction(*iter);
    if( SomeCriteria(*iter) )
        iter = container.erase(iter);
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

Now on to the question; what is the commonly agreed-upon name of this idiom?
I have always called it the **"Iterate-Erase Idiom"**, but if you google that it comes up mostly empty.

Comment: You should actually use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: I am not sure if this idiom has a name, but you can avoid it by iterating from the back, in which case you could use a `for` loop with an unconditional `--iter` in it.

Comment: why would I want to avoid it? please elaborate